# Syntax error on MERGE statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a MERGE statement in Go:

```
query := "MERGE staged ON (email=$1)" +
" WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (email, secret, passwd, ts, newAcct)" +
" VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4,TRUE)" +
" WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE staged SET" +
" newAcct=TRUE, existingUser=NULL, secret=$2, ts=$4"

_, err := db.Exec(query, email, secret, passwd, time.Now())
```

but I got this error:

```
pq: S:"ERROR" F:"scan.l" R:"scanner_yyerror" L:"1001" M:"syntax error at or near \"MERGE\"" P:"1" C:"42601"
```

The same happens in MySQL:

```
Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MERGE staged ON (email=?) WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (email, secret, passwd, t' at line 1
```

What's wrong?

Comment: MySQL does not have a MERGE statement.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`MERGE` is not supported by `MySQL`, The equivalent for that is

**[INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)**

Try this,

```
INSERT INTO tableName (email, secret, passwd, ts, newAcct) 
VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,TRUE)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE newAcct=TRUE, existingUser=NULL, secret=$2, ts=$4
```

but be sure `email` is set as `Primary Key` or `Unique`.

Comment: It's a generic app., to be used in both engines

Comment: The best I can do is check if the email exist, for then to use INSERT or UPDATE.