# merge two large tables with unique values

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

I have to large tables, a main one (TableA) with around 14 million records and a second one I want to merge into it with 20 million records (TableB). For the most part the first is a subset of the second.

I tried making a Unique Index using 2 or 3 fields combined that would identify records as such but MySql wouldn't do it.

I then made my own field 'Unique' by concatenating those three fields.

My question is how do I an import TableB into TableA using only unique records i.e. ones where the value in Unique field in TableB does not already exist in Unique field in TableA.  Since I could not make the Unique field an actual unique index will/should I try to make each one a PK and or ordinary index in the respective tables?

Any thoughts on how to do this efficiently appreciated.

Comment: Refer to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624752/syntax-error-on-merge-statement insert on duplicate key update. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html for docs

Answer (score 0):

Use the sql union statement.

```
    "select * from tableA join tableb"
```